# How can I go back to command line?

Tags: command-line, gedit, ipython

When I run ipython notebook or gedit in Terminal,
the command line does not appear and it stops somewhere.
How can I go back to command line mode?

Comment: Could you take a screenshoot so we understand better what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean how do you return to a "prompt" after opening a GUI from command line? If so then:

Usually when you close the GUI window you'll return to a prompt, if not you can force it to close by pressing ctrl + c from the command line window.

If you want to run the GUI application but continue to use the command prompt you can run the command to launch the GUI application with an '&' after it, for example:

```
gedit test.txt &
```

Which will run it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already executed command then press CTRL + Z to pause the process and then type bg to send it to background

you can bring process to foreground by entering fg